# Qual a diferença entre actionlistener e action?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

Qual a diferença entre **actionListener** e **action**? Quando usar um ou outro?

```
<h:commandButton action="xxxx" actionListener="zzzz" id="teste"/>
```

Comment: Em que contexto?

Comment: `<h:commandButton action="xxxx" actionListener="zzzz" id="teste"/>`

Comment: Edite a pergunta e adicione isso direto nela, para que não fique vaga e seja fechada.

Comment: Resposta:[Differences between action and actionListener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener) se souber inglês, nesse link tem uma explicação bem completa sobre diferenças entre eles e quando usar um ou outro.

Comment: O link está apontando para a mesma pergunta

Comment: opa, corrigido.

Answer (score 2):

Apesar de você poder utilizá-los da mesma forma ( executar ações ), acho que a pergunta melhor é "quando" utilizar um a despeito de outro.

**Action**

Você deveria usar uma action se sua intenção é **executar uma lógica de negócio ou navegar entre páginas**. O método da action pode retornar uma String indicando a regra de navegação.

**ActionListener**

Você deveria usar uma actionListener se o que você quer fazer é **executar uma lógica relacionada a view ou disparar uma ação antes de uma lógica de negócio.** A lógica invocada por uma actionListener está mais ligada a detalhes da tela do que puramente regras de negócio.

Pra não ficar no 'copia-cola', 
http://blog.triadworks.com.br/quando-usar-action-ou-actionlistener-com-jsf